# Android Volley String Request Null Value in Params

Tags: android, android-volley

While String request the post params value getting null and shows the error

NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference

I have done debugging and one of the values is coming as null.
Here is my code,

```
public void getResponsePOST(Activity activity, final String[] name,
        final String[] value) {
    final CustomProgressBar pDialog = new CustomProgressBar(activity,R.drawable.loading);

    //pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    String tag_json_obj = "string_req";
    System.out.println("URL PRODUCT"+mRequestUrl);
    // RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, mRequestUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // Log.v("LOG", "9122014 " + response);
                    mResponseListener.responseSuccess(response.toString());
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // Log.v("LOG", "9122014 " + error);
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    mResponseListener.responseFailure(error.getMessage());
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {

            try
            {
                params.put(name[i], value[i]);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
                //System.out.println("Names:"+name[i]);
                //System.out.println("Values:"+value[i]);
            }
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    //Setting Timout Parameter : Bibin
    sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(1800 * 1000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES , DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(sr, tag_json_obj);
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Share some code, also before trying to assign the value which is received as null, try adding a check to ensure that it is not null

Comment: show us your code

Comment: updated the question with code

Comment: name and value having value ? have u check it ur side properly ?

Comment: name coming correctly but one value is coming as null but I am passing that value.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to try this one :-**

```
try {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            System.out.println("Response is : " + response);
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonLogin = new JSONObject(response);
                                if (jsonLogin.getInt("status") == 1) {

                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonLogin.getString("MSG"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN SUCCESS OF LOGIN REQUEST : " + ex.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            System.out.println("ERROR IN LOGIN STRING REQUEST : " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("USERID", "US-485212391");
                    return params;
                }

            };

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("LoggingIn...");
            progressDialog.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(" Exception : " + ex);

        }
```